# Stream definition

Tags: java, stream

I'm reading on Java I/O streams and I'm confused on the correct definition associated with them.

- Some say that a stream is a sort of conveyor belt in which data are transmitted...
- other say that a stream is a flow or
  a sequence of a data...
- other say that a stream is a
  connection to an input or an output
  source...

So what's the correct definition?

Comment: You have nearly 70 questions you haven't accepted. You need to work on your questions so you can get acceptable answers.

Comment: Really? I think I'm free to post any question I want if I respect people and not say offensive things. So If you don't want to answer me simple don't do it. This is Internet a real democracy! Bye

Comment: Repeatedly asking unacceptable questions and not following up answers is not respecting people.  How can you help someone who won't take good advice?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A stream is a concept, but it's not that strict, that just only one description would be correct.

> An I/O Stream **represents** an input source or an output destination. A stream can represent many different kinds of sources and destinations, including disk files, devices, other programs, and memory arrays.
>   Streams **support** many different kinds of data, including simple bytes, primitive data types, localized characters, and objects. Some streams simply pass on data; others manipulate and transform the data in useful ways.
>
> No matter how they work internally, all streams **present the same simple model to programs** that use them: A stream is a sequence of data.

From: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html

Also a stream is either an input stream or output stream. If it is an input stream, in Java it will adhere to the [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) interface, the latter to the [`Outputstream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).

(Side note: In crypto, there's e.g. a difference between stream and block ciphers, where a *stream* cipher is something that does not know (in a very general sense) anything about the future, while a block cipher knows its (maximum) size in advance and the sizes of all coming blocks.)

Comment: Can we say that a stream is a connection to a data? Like a pipe between the data itself (the file..) and the cpu that will fetch the data. Or maybe a pipe from memory to the file (an outputstream)?

Answer (score 1):

I would say a Stream is like all of these, but not exactly any of these.

I would say its an ordered sequence of 8-bit bytes.

Comment: Maybe you should add "potentially infinite" to the definition and call it a day.

Answer (score 1):

> Java programs perform I/O through streams. A stream is an abstraction
>   that either produces or consumes information. A stream is linked to a
>   physical device by the Java I/O system. All streams behave in the same
>   manner, even if the actual physical devices to which they are linked
>   differ. Thus, the same I/O classes and methods can be applied to any
>   type of device. This means that an input stream can abstract many
>   different kinds of input: from a disk file, a keyboard, or a network
>   socket. Likewise, an output stream may refer to the console, a disk
>   file, or a network connection. Streams are a clean way to deal with
>   input/output without having every part of your code understand the
>   difference between a keyboard and a network, for example. Java
>   implements streams within class hierarchies defined in the java.io
>   package.

From: Java The Complete Reference

Answer (score 0):

Java performs I/O throw streams. A stream is an abstraction that either produces or consumes information. A stream is linked to a physical device by the java I/O stream. Streams are a cleaned way to deal with input or output without having every part of code understand.
Java defines two types of stream: byte and character

Answer (score 0):

In my viewpoint stream is actually a conveyor belt as you mention in the first point. Actually there are two types of stream, input, and output. An input stream is used to read the data from the input device like keywords and write that data to the files and output stream is used to read data from the disks, files, etc and write that data to the output device like console, monitor, etc.

In a simple way, it is the bridge that helps to transport things from one point to another.

Answer (score 0):

Just think it this way: Streams are objects that you can ask for pieces of data or send pieces of data to.