# Java I/O stream definition and subtypes

Tags: java

I'm new to I/O in Java, and read in one of the posts on this site that:

> All streams behave in the same manner, even if the actual physical devices to which they are linked differ. Thus, the same I/O classes and methods can be applied to any type of device

Quoted from: [Stream definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327904/stream-definition)

What I can't wrap my head around is how is it that all streams (take the different byte stream subtypes for example - **BufferedInputStream**, **FilterInputStream**, **ObjectInputStream**, .., etc.) behave in the same manner and can be connected to any physical device, when they are implemented as different classes to supposedly offer varying functionality and accomodate different sources/destinations? For example, can I use **ObjectInputStream** or **FileOutputStream** to read from and write to the console? Different streams, different devices, and all (streams) can be connected to all (devices) - I'm at loss here..

Answer (score 3):

The quote does not say that you can connect *any* stream to *any* device, as you are saying. There are different implementations of `InputStream` and `OutputStream` that connect to specific devices - for example, `FileInputStream` connects to a file on the filesystem, and `ByteArrayInputStream` connects to a byte array in memory.

The main idea that the quote is explaining is that all those different kinds of streams are all extensions of the classes `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, so that you can do all the common operations on streams using any of the specific kinds of streams, regardless of where the specific kind of stream reads or writes data from or to.

Some streams are wrappers around other streams, adding specific functionality. For example, `BufferedOutputStream` adds buffering to an underlying stream. This is often useful because for some streams, writing in blocks is more efficient than writing byte by byte - `BufferedOutputStream` collects bytes that you write into a buffer, which is then written to the underlying stream as one block. `ObjectOutputStream` is another wrapper, which adds the functionality to convert serializable Java objects to bytes which can be written to an underlying stream.

Comment: But it says " the same I/O classes and methods can be applied to any type of device", which refers to the specific concrete classes. The common core functionality established in InputStream and OutputStream may give context for understanding the first part of the statement about all streams behaving similarly - your point about delivering common functionality through the different implementations,  but the part about same classes and methods being linked to different devices is confined in its interpretation to meaning distinct concrete classes (streams)

Comment: The only way that statement would make sense to me is if by "All streams" in "All streams behave in the same manner," it means all streams taken individually, not relative to each other, such that  a given type of stream behaves in the same way even if it was connected to different devices - that is, regardless of the usage scenario, a stream still behaves the same since the interface (class methods) is the same and abstracts the different hardware peculiarities. That then goes for all streams.

Comment: The issue with this interpretation is that language people don't give it much approval (though don't entirely exclude it, still).

Comment: @Surfer Don't make it too complicated.

Comment: Very constructive, Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use every Stream for every device. According to the definition in your question (bold by me),

> All streams **behave** in the same manner.

So you can use every Stream the same, which means every `Stream` has the same methods since they inherit from `java.io.OutputStream` or `java.io.InputStream`.

So it does not matter whether you want to write to the console or a file or a networt socket, you can e.g. always write a byte array to the device.

Nonetheless, there are different implementations which handle writing this byte array differently.